# Inviting users to share a Firebase object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have an app with checklists where I want to be able to share checklists with other users. Those users might not be registered yet in my app. Currently my database is structured as follows:

```
{
    "checklists" : {
        "-KQKfnuGEhhoSIXyFj71" : {
            "admins" : [
                { "C9fdXO6jWTZIxzgbhy0K10TEBqx1" : true },
                {"ZQKHTbTlVMQwnZzFkQUcJF84SaA3" : true }
            ],
            "users" : {
                "-KQKfnuGEhhoSIXyFj74" : {
                    "email" : "admin1@example.com",
                    "uid" : "C9fdXO6jWTZIxzgbhy0K10TEBqx1",
                    "active" : true,
                    "name" : "Moses"
                },
                "-KQKfnuGEhhoSIXyFj75" : {
                    "email" : "admin2@example.com",
                    "uid" : "ZQKHTbTlVMQwnZzFkQUcJF84SaA3",
                    "active" : true,
                    "name" : "John"
                },
                "-KQKfnuGEhhoSIXyFj76" : {
                    "email" : "user1@example.com",
                    "uid" : "1ZxxYFGzoCPIc7Am07GVRxSN7xT2",
                    "active" : true,
                    "name" : "Kate"
                },
                "-KQKfnuGEhhoSIXyFj77" : {
                    "email" : "user2@example.com",
                    "active" : false
                }
            },
            "data" : {
                "task1" : "hello",
                "task2" : "good bye"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My bolt file is as follows:

```
// admin can do both read/ write to the while checklist
path /checklists/{checklistId} {
  read() { isChecklistAdmin(checklistId) }
  write() { isChecklistAdmin(checklistId)  }
}

// users of checklist can do read/write on data only
path /checklists/{checklistId}/data {
  read() { isChecklistUser(checklistId) }
  write() { isChecklistUser(checklistId)  }
}

// users of checklist can add/ remove themselves from the list by updating active flag
path /checklists/{checklistId}/users/{checklistUserId} {
    // all checklist users can read other users
    read() { isChecklistUser(checklistId) } 

    // only admin (implicit) or the user can accept/reject (active) invitation or update their details
    write() { isChecklistUser(checklistId) && ref.parent().email == auth.email } 
}

// is authenticated user in the list of checklist admins?
isChecklistAdmin(checklistId) { isSignedIn() &&  root.checklists[checklistId].admins[auth.uid] != null }

// is authenticated user in the list of checklist users (test email ==)
isChecklistUser(checklistId) { isSignedIn() && root.checklists[checklistId].users['*'].email == auth.email }

isSignedIn() { auth != null }
```

The flow I had in mind was:

1. Admin adds a node under users which has the email of the invited user
2. Admin sends an email invite (I would have liked to use Firebase invites but I don't see how to integrate it in this scenario - would love suggestions).
3. User registers/ logins and updates active flag to true

My question: if you look at the isChecklistUser function, you will find I am using a "wildcard" ("*") since I do not know what that value is. Admin cannot set it at invitation since the user might not be registered yet.

Comment: If a user doesn't have a `uid` yet, you cannot control access for that user. All you can do is lock them out (with `auth != null`).

Comment: That's easy but does not answer my question. I need a way to invite users to share and manage this

Comment: Since these users won't have an account yet, you can't use `uid` for that. You could probably generate some kind of "invite token" for them: just a random, unguessable string that serves as a shared secret between the inviter and the invitee.